# How to create reports for the agents which are available in the common queues in salesforce?

Tags: reporting

how to create reports for the agents which are available in the common queues in salesforce? Their are 2 queues, I want to create the report for those agents which are present in both queues A and B.

Answer (score 0):

To create reports for the agents who are available in the common queues, you can follow the below steps:

- Create a custom report type for **queue members**, as described in [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.queues_membership_reporting.htm&language=en_US&type=5) article.
- In the report builder, select the custom report type you created and click Continue.
- In the **Filters** pane, add a filter for **Queue Name** and set the operator to equals and the value to A. This will show only the members of **queue A**.
- In the **Outline** pane, click **Add group** and select **User** or **Group Name**. This will group the report by the names of the queue members.
- In the **Fields** pane, drag and drop **Queue Name** to the **Preview** pane. This will show the name of the queue for each member.
- Click **Save & Run** to run the report. You should see a list of names and queue names for queue A.
- To filter the report for only those agents who are also in queue B, click **Edit** on the Report Run page.
- In the **Filters** pane, click **Add filter** and select **Cross Filter**. Set the filter to show **Queue Members with Queue**.
- In the sub-filters, set **Queue Name** equals **B**. This will show only those queue members who are also in queue B.
- Click **Save & Run** to run the report. You should see a list of names and queue names for both queue **A and B**.